# ASP.NET Web Api 2 routing convention strange implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

We all know Web API 2 routing conventions and how we can use the following to automatically map onto ApiController types and actions:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "Default",
            "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );


public class AbcdefghijklmnoController : ApiController
{
    public int Test()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

This works as expected, I get 5 when calling api/Abcdefghijklmno/test. But now I want to create Controller types that don't explicitely end with Controller in the end, combined with a custom Controller discovery mechanism as outlined in http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/.

```
public class Abcdefghijklmno : ApiController
{
    public int Test()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

The crazy thing is now that I can get the value 5 from route api/abcde/test, so what the convention based routing is really doing is simply chopping off **the length of the string "Controller" from the type's name**. Apart from this extremely naive implementation from Web API 2, is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Well, you can use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) instead which is one of the best features in WebAPI 2 framework

Comment: I'm building a generic framework where I'm mapping interface implementations straight to API controllers, so that's no go for my case :)

Comment: That sounds horrific what you are trying to do

Comment: Sure, and I would agree if I were writing a classical WebAPI project, but this stuff is hidden in an opinionated framework layer for which the implementor doesn't even know it's WebAPI under the hood.